# What does the attitude possibly mean in this context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I’d like to know what “the attitude” in this interview below in which a musician Damon Albarn says likely means.
Is it something like what musicians or singers do during their performance to make them look cool?

> Your show at Disney is you on piano. Whose playing inspires you?

> “Thelonious Monk is my favorite. And I was very lucky to spend a bit of time with Rubén González, just watching him play. It’s a very nice thing to be able to do something that doesn’t require any amplification. But it’s actually quite hard, doing a whole concert on piano. It’s not hard playing in a band.”

> Hard because it’s so exposed?

> “You can’t hide behind anything. You learn whether the songs are any good or whether they were popular at the time because of the sound and **the attitude**. It’s a day of reckoning — and one, to be honest, that not much modern music could withstand.”

Comment: It's slightly unclear whether he means the attitude of the performer or of the audiences. But it's not integral to his main point: "When playing solo, you find out whether songs of the past became popular based on their intrinsic musical merit, or for external reasons."

Comment: I see. Thanks very much for your help. I asked this question on other forum 5 hours ago, and have got no answer...thought this question might be really difficult  haha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OED

> **Attitude:**
>
> **6.b. any highly independent or individual outlook, approach, appearance, etc.; self-possession; style, swagger, front;**
>
> 1975   Rolling Stone 24 Apr. 52/1   *Natty dreadlocks means hair with an attitude: kinky, jungle thick and matted into tortuous antibraids.*
>
> 1988   Tower Records' Top Feb. 20/4   *You got to go at the business with an attitude or you get nowhere.*

Comment: Ah, Thank you so much!